# how to use hostname variable in single quoted?

Tags: bash, quoting

In the bash file named "input_data"

```
LA=$1
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST '"'$LA'":9200/human_flow/human_flow/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @$2.json
```

When running command

```
 ./input_data localhost human_flow
```

give error message

```
bash-3.2$ ./input_data localhost human_flow
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "localhost"
```

localhost can be resolved

```
bash-3.2$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.156 ms
```

use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

```
bash-3.2$ ./input_data 127.0.0.1 human_flow
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: I mean it's pretty obvious it can't resolve `"localhost"`.  Why do you have embedded double quotes surrounding it?

Comment: curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST '$LA:9200/human_flow/human_flow/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @$2.json also error

Comment: That's correct, it is. Why do you think you need to use single quotes, either to make your double-quotes literal or otherwise?

Comment: solved. Thank you.

Comment: To be clear, you *should* be using double-quotes -- if you just leave out quotes entirely it'll look like it works but be buggy. See http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct usage would look like:

```
curl \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' \
  -XPOST \
  --data-binary "@$2.json" \
  "$LA:9200/human_flow/human_flow/_bulk?pretty"
```

- All expansions are in double quotes -- neither in single quotes (which prevents them from being expanded) nor unquoted.
- Double quotes must not be inside single quotes if they are expected to have semantic meaning.
- By POSIX convention, positional arguments should be specified *after* all optional arguments. Applications following GNU conventions don't strictly require this, but following it across-the-board avoids surprises.